# Ajax responded html data not rendering

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

Ajax response must display with the html css styling. The issue it does not render as it should be
**Front end page**

```
<div class="mailListView">
<table id="tblMailList" border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" bordercolor="#9E9E9E">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Subject</th>
      <th>From</th>
      <th>Sent Date</th>
      <th>To</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="mailListBody">
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div class="mailView">
<table id="tblMailView" width="60%" border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" class="mailSubject">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" class="mailFrom">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="10%">Sent Date</td>
      <td width="90%" class="sentDate">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>To</td>
      <td class="mailTo">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" class="mailAttachments">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><div class="mailBody">&nbsp;</div></td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

JQuery

```
$(function() {
    /* Default Mail List Request */
    var items;
    $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "./mailList.php",
             dataType: 'json',
             success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function(index, element) {
                    items += '<tr><td class="messageid" data-messageid="'+element.messageid+'">'+element.subject+'</td><td>'+element.mailfrom+'</td><td align="right">'+element.date+'</td><td>'+element.mailto+'</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>';
                });
                $('.mailListBody').html('');
                $('.mailListBody').html(items); 
             },
             error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
                  if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                      alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
                  } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                      alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
                  } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                      alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
                  } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                      alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
                  } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                      alert('Time out error.');
                  } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                      alert('Ajax request aborted.');
                  } else {
                      alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
                  }
              }
        }).done(function(){
            $('.messageid').on('click', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var $row = $(this).closest("tr"); 
                var messageid = $row.find('.messageid').data('messageid');
                var mailString;
                    $.ajax({
                         type: "POST",
                         url: "./mailView.php",
                         data: { messageid : messageid },
                         dataType: 'json',
                         success: function (data) {
                            $.each(data, function(index, element) {
                                $('.mailSubject').html(element.subject);
                                $('.mailFrom').html(element.mailfrom);
                                $('.sentDate').html(element.date);
                                $('.mailTo').html(element.mailto);
                                $('.mailBody').html('');
                                mailString = element.msgbody;
                                mailString.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");
                            });
                         },
                         error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
                              if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                                  alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
                              } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                                  alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
                              } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                                  alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
                              } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                                  alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
                              } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                                  alert('Time out error.');
                              } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                                  alert('Ajax request aborted.');
                              } else {
                                  alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
                              }
                          }
                    }).done(function(){
                        $(".mailBody").html(mailString);
                    });
                });
});
```

Data which comes to "mailString variable" is printed on front end page following manner

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"\n "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">\n<!-- saved from url=(0053)http://tedgoas.github.io/Cerberus/cerberus-fluid.html -->\n<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">\n<head>\n <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">\n <!-- utf-8 works for most cases -->\n <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"> <!-- Forcing initial-scale shouldn\'t be necessary -->\n <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> <!-- Use the latest (edge) version of IE rendering engine -->\n <title>New Candidate Mail Template</title> <!-- The title tag shows in email notifications, like Android 4.4. -->\n <!-- Web Font / font-face : BEGIN -->\n <!-- All other clients get the webfont reference; some will render the font and others will silently fail to the fallbacks. More on that here: http://stylecampaign.com/blog/2015/02/webfont-support-in-email/ -->\n <!--[if !mso]>\n <link href=\'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700\' rel=\'stylesheet\' type=\'text/css\'>\n <![endif]-->\n <!-- Web Font / font-face : END -->\n <!-- CSS Reset -->\n <style>\n /* What it does: Remove spaces around the email design added by some email clients. */\n /* Beware: It can remove the padding / margin and add a background color to the compose a reply window. */\n html,\n body {\n margin: 0 auto !important;\n padding: 0 !important;\n height: 100% !important;\n width: 100% !important;\n font: 14px \'Roboto\', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;\n color: #212121;\n }\n\n /* What it does: Stops email clients resizing small text. */\n * {\n -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;\n -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;\n }\n\n /* What is does: Centers email on Android 4.4 */\n div[style*="margin: 16px 0"] {\n margin: 0 !important;\n }\n\n /* What it does: Stops Outlook from adding extra spacing to tables. */\n table,\n td {\n mso-table-lspace: 0pt !important;\n mso-table-rspace: 0pt !important;\n }\n\n /* What it does: Fixes webkit padding issue. Fix for Yahoo mail table alignment bug. Applies table-layout to the first 2 tables then removes for anything nested deeper. */\n table {\n border-spacing: 0 !important;\n border-collapse: collapse !important;\n table-layout: fixed !important;\n margin: 0 auto !important;\n }\n\n table table table {\n table-layout: auto;\n }\n\n /* What it does: Uses a better rendering method when resizing images in IE. */\n img {\n -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;\n }\n\n /* What it does: A work-around for iOS meddling in triggered links. */\n .mobile-link--footer a,\n a[x-apple-data-detectors] {\n color: inherit !important;\n text-decoration: underline !important;\n }\n\n h2 {\n margin: 27px 0 8px;\n display: block;\n font-size: 28px;\n font-weight: normal;\n color: #212121;\n }\n\n h3 {\n font-size: 21px;\n font-weight: normal;\n margin: 0 0 18px 0;\n }\n\n a {\n text-decoration: none;\n color: #0066cc;\n }\n\n p {\n margin: 0;\n }\n </style>\n <!-- Desktop Outlook chokes on web font references and defaults to Times New Roman, so we force a safe fallback font. -->\n <!--[if mso]>\n <style>\n html, body { /* Did I say \'Roboto\'? Not on Outlook. Override earlier selector */\n font: 14px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;\n }\n </style>\n <![endif]-->\n <!-- Progressive Enhancements -->\n <style>\n\n /* What it does: Hover styles for buttons */\n .button-td,\n .button-a {\n transition: all 100ms ease-in;\n }\n .button-td:hover,\n .button-a:hover {\n background: #555555 !important;\n border-color: #555555 !important;\n }\n\n /* Media Queries */\n @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {\n\n /* What it does: Forces elements to resize to the full width of their container. Useful for resizing images beyond their max-width. */\n .fluid,\n .fluid-centered {\n width: 100% !important;\n max-width: 100% !important;\n height: auto !important;\n margin-left: auto !important;\n margin-right: auto !important;\n }\n /* And center justify these ones. */\n .fluid-centered {\n margin-left: auto !important;\n margin-right: auto !important;\n }\n\n /* What it does: Forces table cells into full-width rows. */\n .stack-column,\n .stack-column-center {\n display: block !important;\n width: 100% !important;\n max-width: 100% !important;\n direction: ltr !important;\n border-left: none !important;\n }\n /* And center justify these ones. */\n .stack-column-center {\n text-align: center !important;\n }\n\n /* What it does: Generic utility class for centering. Useful for images, buttons, and nested tables. */\n .center-on-narrow {\n text-align: center !important;\n display: block !important;\n margin-left: auto !important;\n margin-right: auto !important;\n float: none !important;\n }\n table.center-on-narrow {\n display: inline-block !important;\n }\n .adjust-margin-mobile {\n margin: 0 -2px !important;\n }\n }\n\n </style>\n\n <!--[if mso]>\n <style>\n\n </style>\n <!--<![endif]-->\n\n</head>\n<body width="100%" bgcolor="#eeeeee" style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">\n <center style="width: 100%; background: #eeeeee; margin: 0; padding: 0;">\n <!--\n Set the email width. Defined in two places:\n 1. max-width for all clients except Desktop Windows Outlook, allowing the email to squish on narrow but never go wider than 600px.\n 2. MSO tags for Desktop Windows Outlook enforce a 600px width.\n -->\n <!--[if mso]>\n <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" align="center" bgcolor="#fff" style="background: #fff; width: 630px;">\n <tr>\n <td>\n <![endif]-->\n\n <div style="width: 100%; background: #fff;">\n <!-- Email Header : BEGIN -->\n <!--[if mso]>\n <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="630" align="center" style="width: 630px;">\n <tr>\n <td>\n <![endif]-->\n <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" style="max-width: 630px; background: #fff">\n <tbody>\n <tr>\n <td style="padding: 20px 27px; text-align: left">\n <a href="https://example.com" title="Advertiser Centre">\n <!-- todo nz check -->\n <img border="0" src="https://example.com/Content/Images/Logos/logo.png" width="159" height="63"\n alt=" Logo">\n </a>\n </td>\n </tr>\n </tbody>\n </table>\n <!--[if mso]>\n </td>\n </tr>\n </table>\n <![endif]-->\n <!-- Email Header : END -->\n </div>\n <!--[if mso]>\n </td>\n </tr>\n </table>\n <![endif]-->\n\n <div style="max-width: 630px; margin: auto;">\n <!--[if mso]>\n <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="630" align="center" style="width: 630px;">\n <tr>\n <td>\n <![endif]-->\n <!-- Email Body : BEGIN -->\n \n\n<table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" width="100%"\n style="max-width: 630px;">\n<tbody>\n<!-- 1 Column Text + Button : BEGIN -->\n<tr>\n <td bgcolor="#eeeeee" style="padding: 27px 27px;">\n <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" align="left" style="text-align: left">\n <tbody>\n <tr>\n <td>\n <h2 style="color: #212121; font-size: 28px; font-weight: normal; margin: 0 0 9px">Hi Application Email,</h2>\n </td>\n </tr>\n <tr>\n <td style="font-size: 14px; mso-height-rule: exactly;">\n <p style="margin: 0;">\n You have a new applicant for the role of <strong>Experienced Forklift Drivers - High-Reach &amp; Counter Balance</strong> (CaesarstoneFORKIE):\n </p>\n </td>\n </tr>\n </tbody>\n </table>\n </td>\n</tr>\n<!-- 1 Column Text + Button : BEGIN -->\n<!-- 2 Even Columns : BEGIN -->\n<tr>\n<td bgcolor="#eeeeee" align="center" height="100%" valign="top" width="100%">\n<!--[if mso]>\n <table role="presentation" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" width="630" style="width: 630px;">\n <tr>\n <td align="center" valign="top" width="630">\n<![endif]-->\n<table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" width="100%" style="max-width: 630px;">\n<tbody>\n<tr>\n<td align="center" valign="top" style="text-align: left">\n<!--[if mso]>\n <table role="presentation" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" width="630" style="width: 630px;">\n <tr>\n <td align="left" valign="top" width="321" style="width: 321px;">\n<![endif]-->\n <div style="display: inline-block; margin: 0 -11px; border-left: 9px solid #eeeeee; margin-right: 9px; max-width: 295px; min-width: 200px; vertical-align: top; width: 100%;" class="stack-column adjust-margin-mobile">\n <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">\n <tbody>\n <tr>\n <td style="padding: 0 0 9px">\n <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">\n <tbody>\n <tr>\n <td style="background: #fff; padding: 27px 27px 36px;">\n <h3 style="font-size: 21px; font-weight: normal; margin: 0 0 18px 0; padding: 0;">Candidate details</h3>\n <table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" width="100%">\n <tbody>\n <tr>\n <td style="padding-bottom: 18px;">\n <p style="margin: 0;">\n Name\n </p>\n <p style="font-weight: bold; margin: 0;">\n <a style="text-decoration: none; color: #0066cc;" href="https://example.com/EasyAccess/Secure?token=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&tracking=TMC-SAU-ADV-NONRR-EA-Candidate" title="View candidate">Abc ak s</a>\n </p>\n </td>\n </tr>\n <tr>\n <td style="padding-bottom: 18px;">\n <p style="margin: 0;">\n Email\n </p>\n <p style="font-weight: bold; margin: 0;">\n <a style="text-decoration: none; color: #0066cc;" href="abc@gmail.com" title="Email Maurice Sagigi">abc@gmail.com</a>\n </p>\n </td>\n </tr>\n <tr>\n <td style="padding-bottom: 18px;">\n <p style="margin: 0;">\n Phone\n </p>\n <p style="font-weight: bold; margin: 0;">\n 0496696969\n </p>\n </td>\n </tr>\n <tr>\n <td style="padding-bottom: 18px;">\n <p style="margin: 0;">\n Most recent job title\n </p>\n <p style="font-weight: bold; margin: 0;">\n Truck Driver\n </p>\n </td>\n </tr>\n <tr>\n <td style="padding-bottom: 18px;">\n <p style="margin: 0;">\n Company\n </p>\n <p style="font-weight: bold; margin: 0;">\n dxcvv Heavy sdf sdf\n </p>\n </td>\n </tr>\n <tr>\n <td>\n <p style="margin: 0;">\n Time in role\n </p>\n <p style="font-weight: bold; margin: 0;">\n 20 years\n </p>\n </td>\n </tr>\n </tbody>\n </table>\n </td>\n\n </tr>\n <tr>\n <td style="background: #fff; border-top: 9px solid #eee; padding: 27px 27px 36px;">\n <h3 style="font-size: 21px; font-weight: normal; margin: 0 0 18px 0; padding: 0;">Found what you need?</h3>\n <table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" width="168" height="75" style="height: 75px; width: 168px;">\n <tbody>\n <tr>\n <td style="height: 75px; padding-right: 18px; width: 55px;">\n <a href="https://example.com/EasyAccess/Secure?token=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&actionConfirmation=shortlist&tracking=TMC-SAU-ADV-NONRR-EA-Shortlist" title="Shortlist candidate" style="color: #212121;">\n <img border="0" src="https://example.com/Content/Images/Emails/email-shortlist-icon.png" alt="&#10003;" width="55" height="57" style="width: 55px; height: 57px;"/>\n <br/>Shortlist\n </a>\n </td>\n <td style="height: 75px; width: 75px;">\n <a href="https://example.com/EasyAccess/Secure?token=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&actionConfirmation=notsuitable&tracking=TMC-SAU-ADV-NONRR-EA-NotSuitable" title="Candidate not suitable" style="color: #212121;">\n <img border="0" src="https://example.com/Content/Images/Emails/email-not-suitable-icon.png" alt="X" width="75" height="57" style="width: 75px; height: 57px;" />\n <br/>Not Suitable\n </a>\n </td>\n </tr>\n </tbody>\n </table>\n </td>\n </tr>\n </tbody>\n </table>\n </td>\n </tr>\n </tbody>\n </table>\n\n </div>\n\n<!--[if mso]>\n </td>\n <td width="9" style="width: 9px;"></td>\n <td align="left" valign="top" width="321" style="width: 321px;">\n<![endif]-->\n <div style="display: inline-block; margin: 0 -2px; max-width: 295px; min-width: 200px; vertical-align: top; width: 100%;" class="stack-column">\n <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">\n <tbody>\n <tr>\n <td>\n <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" style="font-size: 14px; text-align: left;">\n <tbody>\n <tr>\n\n <td style="background: #fff; border-top: none; padding: 27px 27px 36px;">\n <h3 style="font-size: 21px; font-weight: normal; margin: 0 0 18px 0; padding: 0;">Get the full picture</h3>\n <p style="margin-bottom: 18px;">\n View detailed applicant information\n </p>\n <p style="margin-bottom: 27px;">\n Use our tools to quickly and effectively find the right candidates.\n </p>\n <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="left" style="margin: auto;">\n <tbody>\n <tr>\n <td style="background: #e60278; border-radius: 3px; text-align: left;" class="button-td">\n <a href="https://example.com/EasyAccess/Secure?token=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&tracking=TMC-SAU-ADV-NONRR-EA-ViewApplicant" title="View applicant" style="background: #e60278; border: 15px solid #e60278; border-radius: 2px; display: block; font-size: 18px; line-height: 1.1; text-align: center; text-decoration: none;" class="button-a">\n &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="color: #ffffff">View applicant</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;\n </a>\n </td>\n </tr>\n </tbody>\n </table>\n </td>\n </tr>\n </tbody>\n </table>\n </td>\n </tr>\n </tbody>\n </table>\n </div>\n<!--[if mso]>\n </td>\n </tr>\n </table>\n<![endif]-->\n</td>\n</tr>\n</tbody>\n</table>\n<!--[if mso]>\n </td>\n </tr>\n </table>\n<![endif]-->\n</td>\n</tr>\n<!-- Two Even Columns : END -->\n<!-- Clear Spacer : BEGIN -->\n<tr>\n <td height="20" style="font-size: 0; line-height: 0;">\n &nbsp;\n </td>\n</tr>\n<!-- Clear Spacer : END -->\n\n</tbody>\n</table>\n <!-- Email Body : END -->\n <!-- Email Footer : BEGIN -->\n <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" width="100%"\n style="max-width: 630px;">\n <tbody>\n <tr>\n <td style="width: 100%; mso-height-rule: exactly;text-align: left; font-size: 14px; padding: 18px 27px 0;">\n Need help? Please contact <a style="text-decoration: none;color: #0066cc;" href="https://example.com/ContactUs"\n title="Customer Service">Customer Service</a> on <img border="0" src="https://example.com/Content/Images/Emails/email-phone-icon.png" style="padding-right: 5px;"/> 1300 658 700.\n </td>\n </tr>\n <tr>\n <td style="width: 100%; mso-height-rule: exactly; text-align: left; font-size: 14px;">\n <p><!-- Footer padding -->&nbsp;</p>\n </td>\n </tr>\n </tbody>\n </table>\n <!-- Email Footer : END -->\n <!--[if mso]>\n </td>\n </tr>\n </table>\n <![endif]-->\n </div>\n </center>\n\n</body>\n</html><br><hr size=1><br><br>\n\n&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>
```

Comment: try to add append function inside $.each to append all received elements inside mailListBody

Comment: mailListBody is already viewed nicely. the issue is in mailString which will be inserted inside mailBody div @developerbh

Comment: If you are wanting the styles in that head you would need to get them yourself and append them to existing page

Comment: i'll forget the styles for the moment, but its not rendering as html. Thats the problem

Comment: @Swarne27 If it's not rendering as HTML, what is it rendering as?

Comment: I have uploaded how it renders at the bottom of question @Ouroborus starts with <!DOCTYPE ....

Comment: @Swarne27 Ah, so it renders the HTML as raw text. Sounds like an encoding problem. Perhaps something like [`decodeURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI) or [`decodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) would help.

Comment: It gives "URIError: malformed URI sequence" when I use decodeURI